# Looking for FOSS tool that converts polygons into polylines?

Tags: software-recommendations, polyline-creation

I'm trying to convert a polygon layer into a polyline layer using a free open source tool. I have been able to perform this task in ArcGIS but can't find any free tools that will do the same thing.

Has anyone come across a tool that can do this?

Comment: The term would be LineString or MultiLineString in many tools. ;)

Comment: Now that you have an answer about how to do this using ogr2ogr, I think that you should re-word your question to ask that as a more focused question.  If you are seeking more software recommendations then don't forget that there is a [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

`ogr2ogr` can do it:

I have some tectonic plates polygons:

```
$ ogrinfo PB2002_plates.shp
INFO: Open of `PB2002_plates.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
1: PB2002_plates (Polygon)
```

Convert:

```
$ ogr2ogr -nlt MULTILINESTRING linear.shp PB2002_plates.shp
```

What have I got?

```
$ ogrinfo linear.shp
INFO: Open of `linear.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
1: linear (Line String)
```

The attributes are preserved and the geometry is now LINESTRING:

```
 PlateName (String) = Africa
  LINESTRING (-0.4379 -54.8518,-0.914655 -54.4535,-1.3822 -54.0533,-2.37231 -54.3274,-2.91952 -53.5469,-3.44688 -52
.764,-3.95559 -51.9788,-4.23767 -52.0486,-4.47762 -51.5912,-4.71279 -51.1333,-4.94334 -50.6749,-5.16942 -50.2161,-6
.1
```

Note this converts each feature to a polyline so most borders are still present twice, once for each feature on either side of the border. If you want to convert polygons into a network line data set, that's another problem...